# Sympy plotting backends library unable to save plot

Tags: matplotlib, plot, sympy

I use [sympy plotting backends](https://pypi.org/project/sympy-plot-backends/) library to create plots directly from sympy expressions. As backends i use [matplotlib](https://pypi.org/project/matplotlib/) library. Actually, i don't need to show a plot. I create plot and then i return it as svg string in order to insert it in a web page later. Everything worked fine, but when i started to use new virtual environment (i installed all necessary packages) i got an error. I use the following code:

```
# create two plot: one from init_expr (sympy tree expression) and second from
# fourier_expr (sympy tree expression):
p1 = plot(
        (init_expr, (var, left_bound, right_bound), label_1, line_color_1),
        (fourier_expr, (var, left_bound, right_bound), label_2, line_color_2),
         show = False)

# add axes decorations and legend:
p1.xlabel = var_name
p1.ylabel = "f(" + data.var_name + ")"
p1.legend = True        

# buffer to write svg data:
f = io.StringIO()

# save plot in svg formate in buffer:        
p1.save(f, format = "svg")
    
# return svg string:
return f.getvalue()
```

when execution begins, at line:

```
p1.save(f, format="svg")
```

i get an error:

```
AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'runner'")
```

Any ideas what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I'm the developer of that module. I have two questions. 1 - How did you installed the module? 2 - Run the following code into your environment and let me know the output: `import adaptive;print(adaptive.__version__)`

Comment: What happens if you `p1.save(f, format="png")` ?

Comment: Hi! 1. I unstalled the module with command ```pip install sympy-plot-backends```. And all the necessary modules installed. 2. When i add the ```import adaptive``` line it throws the exception from file adaptive\types.py on line ```from typing_extensions import TypeAlias```. The exceptions is "No module named 'typing_extensions'".

Comment: if ```p1.save(f, format="png")``` the same error as in case of svg occurs ```AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'runner'")```

Comment: i've installed typing_extension module ```pip install typing_extension``` and run ```import adaptive print(adaptive.__version__)``` the result is 0.15.1. Then i run my program and get the desired output (plot as svg string) without exception. It seems that the developers of ```adaptive``` module forgot to mention that their library also depends on ```typing_extension``` module...

Comment: Yep, just checked adaptive source code. You must be using Python < 3.10, which is going to need the `typing_extension` module. I'm going to raise an issue. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @Anton Makarov which Python version are you using?

Comment: I use python 3.8. Thank you for help...